# In Azure release GUI pipeline, can I trigger Stage2 based on the result of Stage1

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

Is it possible to trigger a stage is release GUI pipeline based on the result of previous stage. If Stage1 is successful trigger Stage2 automatically & if Stage1 is partially succeeded ask for approvals to trigger Stage2.

**Azure Release GUI pipeline**
[image: Azure Release GUI pipeline]

If stage1 succeeds(green), trigger stage2 automatically.
If stage1 partially succeeds(yellow), ask for approvals to trigger stage2.

I tried giving custom conditions in pre deployment approval of stage2 but there's no such option.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly solution but may work for you:

You could have two similar stages chained on stage1. Stage2 triggering without approval only for successful stage1. Stage3 triggering with approval for both successful and partially successful stage1.

As a result:

1. Stage1 succeeds -> Stage2 triggers automatically and you never approve stage3
2. Stage1 partiallySucceeds -> Stage2 is skipped and you get approval request for stage3

Comment: And Stage 2 and Stage 3 could both use the same task group, so there's no duplication of steps between stages.